# Scala - modify strings in a list based on their number of occurences

Tags: string, list, scala, increment

Another Scala newbie question since I am not getting how to achieve this in a functional way (mostly coming from a scripting language background):

I have a list of strings:

`val food-list = List("banana-name", "orange-name", "orange-num", "orange-name", "orange-num", "grape-name")`

and where they are duplicated, I'd like to add an incrementing number into the string and get that in a list similar to the input list, like so:

`List("banana-name", "orange1-name", "orange1-num", "orange2-name", "orange2-num", "grape-name")`

I've grouped them up to get counts for them with:

`val freqs = list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(v => List.range(1, v.length + 1))`

Which gives me:

`Map(orange-num -> List(1, 2), banana-name -> List(1), grape-name -> List(1), orange-name -> List(1, 2))`

The order of the list **is important** (it should be in the original order of `food-list`) so I know it's problematic for me to use a Map at this point. The closest I feel I have gotten to a solution is:

```
food-list.map{l =>

    if (freqs(l).length > 1){

            freqs(l).map(n => 
                           l.split("-")(0) + n.toString + "-" + l.split("-")(1))

    } else {
        l
    }
}
```

This of course gives me a wonky output since I am mapping the list of frequencies from the words value in `freqs`

`List(banana-name, List(orange1-name, orange2-name), List(orange1-num, orange2-num), List(orange1-name, orange2-name), List(orange1-num, orange2-num), grape-name)`

How is this done in a Scala fp way without resorting to clumsy for loops and counters?

Comment: Is it ok to count each time the previous occurrences of a given value, or that would be too (O(n^2)) slow?

Comment: for my purposes, I am not going to have any lists too long that that would make a noticeable difference, so previous occurrences wouldn't be a problem, but trying to figure out efficient counting in Scala coming from Python is not very obvious to me at the moment

Comment: The `count` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@count(p:A=>Boolean):Int) method is available on `Seq`s, so that I think might be very similar to Python. Anyway, my solution at the end did not use it, though it required a `reverse`, so it is not the most efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the indices are important, sometimes it's best to keep track of them explicitly using `zipWithIndex` (very similar to Python's `enumerate`):

```
food-list.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._1).values.toList.flatMap{
  //if only one entry in this group, don't change the values
  //x is actually a tuple, could write case (str, idx) :: Nil => (str, idx) :: Nil
  case x :: Nil => x :: Nil
  //case where there are duplicate strings
  case xs => xs.zipWithIndex.map {
    //idx is index in the original list, n is index in the new list i.e. count
    case ((str, idx), n) =>
      //destructuring assignment, like python's (fruit, suffix) = ...
      val Array(fruit, suffix) = str.split("-")
      //string interpolation, returning a tuple
      (s"$fruit${n+1}-$suffix", idx)
  }
//We now have our list of (string, index) pairs;
//sort them and map to a list of just strings
}.sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Efficient and simple:

```
val food = List("banana-name", "orange-name", "orange-num", 
             "orange-name", "orange-num", "grape-name")

def replaceName(s: String, n: Int) = {
  val tokens = s.split("-")
  tokens(0) + n + "-" + tokens(1)
}

val indicesMap = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Int]
val res = food.map { name =>
  {
    val n = indicesMap.getOrElse(name, 1)
    indicesMap += (name -> (n + 1))
    replaceName(name, n)
  }
}
```

Comment: Works, but the mutable map is not entirely idiomatic.

Comment: But it is very intersting here, since it can be done *on the fly*

Comment: @JeanLogeart You are not handling the case of banana-name when the list contains only a single occurrence. You need an extra step beforehand.

Comment: You are right. My solution is then false and I cannot just do it on the fly. I leave it as an alternative even though it does not strictly answer the OP question.

Comment: Well, you could quickly create a lookup table, using groupBy(identity) to check for cardinality. Or if you insist on not creating an extra variable, food.count can work with reduced performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/gist/c5e2c5c050912293b09b?) is an attempt to provide what you expected with `foldLeft`:

```
foodList.foldLeft((List[String](), Map[String, Int]()))//initial value
    ((a/*accumulator, list, map*/, v/*value from the list*/)=>
         if (a._2.isDefinedAt(v))//already seen
             (s"$v+${a._2(v)}" :: a._1, a._2.updated(v, a._2(v) + 1))
         else
             (v::a._1, a._2.updated(v, 1)))
    ._1/*select the list*/.reverse/*because we created in the opposite order*/
```

Comment: Yeah, this version puts the number to the wrong place, though that would complicate unnecessarily, other answers implemented that part very well. :)